# Getting current image to share it in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have an Android application. In that, the slider is working fine, and the share button is also working correctly.

But, the share button is sharing only an image which I have set in code out of the three total images in slider (since I coded in that way), instead of the current image visible in the slider gallery. I simply want to invoke the share button code with the current image, so that the user can share the current image.

Here are some details,
3 ImageView for 3 images in the slider. Also, I have taken these in ViewFlipper:

Image 1

```
       android:id="@+id/imageview1"
       android:tag="bg1"
       android:src="@drawable/image1
```

Image 2

```
       android:id="@+id/imageview2"
       android:tag="bg2"
       android:src="@drawable/image2
```

Image 3

```
       android:id="@+id/imageview3"
       android:tag="bg3"
       android:src="@drawable/image3
```

Till now, I have tried this,

```
    Button btShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareImage);
    btShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            share();
        }
    });
```

Now, here's the share() function code snippet, in which I want the current image. For that, I have taken setTag() and getTag(), but I am still confused. 
Here, I have set the tag for all the 3 images, so that I can get their value.

```
    mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    mImageView.setTag("bg1");

    mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
    mImageView.setTag("bg2");

    mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
    mImageView.setTag("bg3");

    String s = String.valueOf(mViewFlipper.getTag());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (s.equals("bg1"))  /
    {
        // now the code for share button starts, in that a folder gets
        created in the Directory and a default name is given to the 
        image which gets saved there, like

        File f = new File(dir, "savedImage1.png");
```

I am not sure (I don't want to do that either) about the above if-else too, because it isn't good to create "if" for every image, so I need an alternate like an array) or so to work around current Drawable image.

So in the above String s is returning "null", on selecting any image (I checked it by applying Toast and it is showing null in every case).

If I am successful in getting bg1 (for image 1), or bg2 (for image 2), or bg3 (for image 3), for current image in String s, then I can easily run the code to share a particular image only, when it appears on the slider gallery.

Answer (score 2):

Line: `String s = String.valueOf(mViewFlipper.getTag());`

You are trying to read the tag of the ViewFlipper, not the displayed image.

Use `flipper.getDisplayedChild();` to retrieve the displayed ImageView and read the tag off it.

Also, even better would be to prepare an array of the file names you are displaying, and then retrieve the index of displayed image with:
`flipper.indexOfChild(flipper.getCurrentView())`.

Then you could reach into your file name array with this index and write the logic for the image sharing only once.

Comment: Thank you, @Axarydax. I understood the flipper.getDisplayedChild(); and it worked perfectly.

Comment: But, I am still confused about how to create an array and get the value in it, since I have to call BITMAP once. Means I don't want to do it like the following separately,                                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image1); for image1, etc.

Comment: @AmanChawla You can define an int[] array of image IDs in your activity, and have values of R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, etc in it. If you keep the same ordering as in your ViewFlipper, you can use the `indexOfChild` as index for the array to get the image ID.